# How do you fix the "Model not found" error?

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

I cannot play Counter-Strike Condition Zero, because of the following error:

> "Mod_NumForName: models/player/leet/leet.mdl not found"

Why is this happening?

Comment: Uh.. can you rephrase your subject?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a model file, this can be retrieved from [here](http://download.gameszone.ro/cs/models/player/leet/)

You will need to place this file in the /models/player/leet/ directory.

If the problem persists for a different model you can just reinstall the game and apply applicable patches or search [here](http://download.gameszone.ro/cs/) for the files needed.

Answer (score -1):

Check the .res file for your map and see if the file is specified there :) (The game doesn't know where to find that file if it's not specified in there)